# Value do input text não muda quando acionado pelo botão

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um botão de mais na tela que incrementa +1 em cima do valor atual do input, quando eu faço um alert na variável apresenta o valor normal incrementando +1 porém no campo em tela o valor não muda, continua sempre zero, o que eu estou fazendo de errado? será que alguém pode me ajudar? segue o código:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin:0;padding:0;">
                                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="margin:0;padding:0;float:left;width:60%;">
                                        <h6 style="float:left;"><?echo utf8_encode($rowAdicionaisProduct['ingredient']);?></h6>
                                        <small style="float:left;clear:both;color:#ED3237;padding:0px;line-height:10px;"><b>+ R$<?=$rowAdicionaisProduct['unit_price']?></b></small>
                                      </div>
                                      <input type="hidden" name="idIngredientAdds[]" value="<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>">
                                      <input type="hidden" name="ingredient[]" value="<?echo utf8_encode($rowAdicionaisProduct['ingredient']);?>">
                                      <input type="hidden" name="priceAdd[]" id="adicionalPrice<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>" value="<?=$adicionalPrice?>">
                                      <button type="button" class="btnChangeQtdAdd" style="float:left;background:transparent;border:none;margin-top:-15px;" id="decAdd<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>" onclick ="subtrairMenos1Add<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>();"><i style="font-size:19px;color:#ED3237;" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                                      <input type="text" name="qtd_option[]" class="qtdAdicionais" id="qtdIngredientAdicional<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>" style="width:30px;float:left;height:30px;text-align:center;margin-top:-20px;" value="0">
                                      <button type="button" class="btnChangeQtdAdd" style="float:left;background:transparent;border:none;margin-top:-15px;" id="inc<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>" onclick="somarMais1Add<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>();"><i style="font-size:19px;color:#ED3237;" class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                    <script>
                                      function somarMais1Add<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>() {
                                          var n1 = document.getElementById("qtdIngredientAdicional<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>").val;
                                          var n2 = 1;
                                          document.getElementById("qtdIngredientAdicional<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>").val = n1 + 1;
                                      };
                                    </script>
```

Comment: Está criando uma função pra cada botão? É uma péssima forma de fazer isso, permita-me dizer. Bastava uma só função e enviar o id como parâmetro: `function somarMais1Add(id)`, e no HTML: `onclick="somarMais1Add('<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>');"`

Comment: eu só sei fazer assim... não sei fazer de outro jeito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma que está fazendo está muito ruim. Em vez de repetir o script e criar funções baseadas no id vindo do laço do PHP, você pode criar apenas uma única função tanto para incrementar o valor no input quanto para decrementar. Basta enviar para a função dois parâmetros: o `id` do input e outro valor que possa identificar quando é pra somar ou quando é para subtrair.

Por exemplo:

```
onclick="somarSubtrair('<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>');" // para subtrair
onclick="somarSubtrair('<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>', true);" // para somar
```

O `true` no segundo parâmetro significa que você quer somar. Se o segundo parâmetro estiver vazio, significa que quer subtrair.

A função ficaria assim:

```
function somarSubtrair(id, oper) {
   var n1 = +document.getElementById("qtdIngredientAdicional"+id).value;
   document.getElementById("qtdIngredientAdicional"+id).value = n1 + (oper ? +1 : -1);
};
```

Veja que é concatenado o `id` no `document.getElementById` e usa-se `.value` e não `.val` como você está fazendo.

Antes de `document.getElementById` adicionei um sinal de `+` para converter o valor do campo em tipo número para poder fazer a soma.

O operador ternário `(oper ? +1 : -1)` irá verificar se o parâmetro `oper` é `true` e somar `+1`, caso contrário (se for vazio) irá fazer `-1`.

Resumindo, você deve colocar o `<script>` fora do laço do PHP e alterar o `onclick` dos botões, algo assim:

```
<?php
while(condição){
?>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin:0;padding:0;">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="margin:0;padding:0;float:left;width:60%;">
      <h6 style="float:left;"><?echo utf8_encode($rowAdicionaisProduct['ingredient']);?></h6>
      <small style="float:left;clear:both;color:#ED3237;padding:0px;line-height:10px;"><b>+ R$<?=$rowAdicionaisProduct['unit_price']?></b></small>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" name="idIngredientAdds[]" value="<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="ingredient[]" value="<?echo utf8_encode($rowAdicionaisProduct['ingredient']);?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="priceAdd[]" id="adicionalPrice<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>" value="<?=$adicionalPrice?>">
   <button type="button" class="btnChangeQtdAdd" style="float:left;background:transparent;border:none;margin-top:-15px;" id="decAdd<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>" onclick ="somarSubtrair('<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>');"><i style="font-size:19px;color:#ED3237;" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
   <input type="text" name="qtd_option[]" class="qtdAdicionais" id="qtdIngredientAdicional<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>" style="width:30px;float:left;height:30px;text-align:center;margin-top:-20px;" value="0">
   <button type="button" class="btnChangeQtdAdd" style="float:left;background:transparent;border:none;margin-top:-15px;" id="inc<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>" onclick="somarSubtrair('<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>', true);"><i style="font-size:19px;color:#ED3237;" class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
</div>
<?php
}
?>

<script>
function somarSubtrair(id, oper) {
   var n1 = +document.getElementById("qtdIngredientAdicional"+id).value;
   document.getElementById("qtdIngredientAdicional"+id).value = n1 + (oper ? +1 : -1);
};
</script>
```

**Exemplo de funcionamento:**

```js
function somarSubtrair(id, oper) {
   var n1 = +document.getElementById("qtdIngredientAdicional"+id).value;
   document.getElementById("qtdIngredientAdicional"+id).value = n1 + (oper ? +1 : -1);
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
   <button type="button" class="btnChangeQtdAdd" style="float:left;background:transparent;border:none;" id="decAdd<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>" onclick ="somarSubtrair('22');"><i style="font-size:19px;color:#ED3237;" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
   <input type="text" name="qtd_option[]" class="qtdAdicionais" id="qtdIngredientAdicional22" style="width:30px;float:left;height:30px;text-align:center;" value="0">
   <button type="button" class="btnChangeQtdAdd" style="float:left;background:transparent;border:none;" id="inc<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>" onclick="somarSubtrair('22', true);"><i style="font-size:19px;color:#ED3237;" class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
</div>
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
   <button type="button" class="btnChangeQtdAdd" style="float:left;background:transparent;border:none;" id="decAdd<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>" onclick ="somarSubtrair('23');"><i style="font-size:19px;color:#ED3237;" class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
   <input type="text" name="qtd_option[]" class="qtdAdicionais" id="qtdIngredientAdicional23" style="width:30px;float:left;height:30px;text-align:center;" value="0">
   <button type="button" class="btnChangeQtdAdd" style="float:left;background:transparent;border:none;" id="inc<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>" onclick="somarSubtrair('23', true);"><i style="font-size:19px;color:#ED3237;" class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Não sei o que está acontecendo, fiz desse jeito ai e o valor do input continua zerado, mesmo depois de clicar no botão +

Comment: Veja se mostra erro no console

Comment: Resolveu aqui, eu agradeço muito

Answer (score 0):

Altere a sua função da seguinte forma:

```js
 
                                      function somarMais1Add<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>() {
                                          var n1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("qtdIngredientAdicional<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>").value);
                                          var n2 = 1;
                                          document.getElementById("qtdIngredientAdicional<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>").value = n1 + 1;
                                      };
```

Comment: seria legal explicar o q foi alterado e como resolveu o problema, apenas colocar o código não vai ajudar a entender o problema

Comment: eu já fiz isso e não resolveu, continua sem alterar no valor do input